# IntelliTrace with WCF

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I've got a Visual Studio Solution that contains a client application and a WCF Service, which is configured to use IIS rather than the VS Web Server.  When I debug my application with IntelliTrace on, I get information about the client, but do not get any information about the server.  Furthermore, I don't see any "server call" entries in the IntelliTrace output, which I kind of expected since the demos show these for an ASP.Net application (not the same thing, I know, but I was hopeful).

I tried changing the default IIS profile settings as suggested here: http://continuouslyintegrating.blogspot.com/2011/05/windows-7-sp1-iis-and-intellitrace.html, but that had no effect.

Is there something that I'm missing?

David Mullin

Answer (score 0):

Do you have source code for server?

Intellitrace only records events for which it has the source code, if you dont have the source code then I dont think you will be able to get that information

Answer (score 0):

IntelliTrace creates a log for each process that is executing.  Your client applicaiton and your WCF application are in two different process.  If you configure both of them to be startup projects in solution explorer then IntelliTrace will record events for both of them during your debug session.

However you will still only see data from one process at a time in the IntelliTrace window.  If you step from your client code into your service code you should see the IntelliTrace events change to those for the WCF service.